# javac file not found when calling JavaCompiler.run()

Tags: java, compiler-construction, classloader, javac, java-compiler-api

I'm trying to use the **JavaCompiler.run()** to complie dynamically generated source files. 
Below is my program, when I run it I got on the System.err:

> javac: file not found: C:..bla..bla..\test\A.java C:..bla..bla..\test\B.java C:..bla..bla..\test\C.java
>   Usage: javac  
>   use -help for a list of possible options

The files are not compiled, but eveything got compiled when i put in the command prompt

> javac C:..bla..bla..\test\A.java C:..bla..bla..\test\B.java C:..bla..bla..\test\A.java

Here is the complete source code

```
// define the classes
String stringA = "package test;" + " "
    + "public class A { " 
    + "public A() { B b = new B(); b.b(); }" + " "
    + "public static boolean a() { return true;}" + " " 
    + "}";
String stringB = "package test;" + " " 
    + "public class B { " 
    + "public B() { }" + " "
    + "public boolean b() { return new C().c(); }" + " " 
    + "}";
String stringC = "package test;" + " " 
    + "public class C { " 
    + "public C() { }" + " "
    + "public boolean c() { return A.a(); }" + " " 
    + "}";
// Save sources in .java files then compile    
String pathA = store("test/A.java", stringA);
String pathB = store("test/B.java", stringB);
String pathC = store("test/C.java", stringC);

StringBuilder pathBuilder = new StringBuilder();
pathBuilder.append(pathA);
pathBuilder.append(" ");
pathBuilder.append(pathB);
pathBuilder.append(" ");
pathBuilder.append(pathC);

String files = pathBuilder.toString();
// run compiler
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
compiler.run(null, null, null, files);

...
```

The store(filename, source) saves the file source and return the full path to the stored file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I should call **JavaCompiler.run()** this way:

```
compiler.run(null, null, null, pathA, pathB, pathC);
```

just provide each path to a source file as a separate argument instead of concatinating the different paths and providing the **run()** a single argument !
I noticed that not all **javac** options are supported (e.g. classpath) by the compiler provided through **ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()**.